# How do I execute PHP code inside of HTML file?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

I see some websites show the details of the current post like Title,Views,Likes.... But when I look to the URL I see in last of path .HTML  (title-of-page.html).

Like Blogger we see .HTML in the path but there are many PHP codes inside !
How do they do it?

Comment: Probably url rewriting. You can also have your webserver interpret PHP from any other file extension you'd like. This question is too vague for SO though (also not a coding issue per se).

Comment: Hh Thank you... to understand me more.. look at this page url           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54498883/how-do-i-execute-php-code-inside-of-html-file       there is no .php but it runs it 

Comment: Thank you so much Emma that exactly what i need ❤  and thank you also Jeto

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can do anything with PHP inside an HTML file, is through some sort of rest API (or file listeners but that is just extremely complicated). The most common use of PHP inside a HTML file is forms! *yay* You can put a link to a PHP file inside the `action` attribute. For example...

```
<form action="https://example.com/local/or/remote/doStuff.php">
```

This will send all of your form's data (form data) to that PHP file to be processed.

If you actually want to use PHP code inside of a HTML file, like literally putting a `<?php`, then you would need to be God because that is not possible. You need to save it as a .php file.

If you would like to not have to do http://example.com/index.php`?7` and you wanted it to look like http://example.com/index.php then you need to use `POST`. Post is a method, there are two typically used, `POST` and `GET`. People seem to think post is more secure (because it is) so that is why you don't see that wonky `?` in some links. In a form, you can simply add the method attribute and set it to `POST` for it to use the post method. 
For example...

```
<form action="http://example.com/index.php" method="POST">
```

While post isn't bulletproof, it is definitely more secure than GET, it also looks more professional to most people.

Comment: Hh yes i know .. just my question was not clear.. because of my bad english ... i will edit now..   and lemme give you simple one .. how to show .com/view.php?id=7    as a  .com/view/7  or even .com/view/7.html